# cannot push to github, looks like pull didn't update my remote fork

Tags: git, github

there are issues pushing some commits to my forked repo at github

See the current status

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:claudio4j/hal-core (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:claudio4j/hal-core (push)
upstream        git://github.com/hal/core.git (fetch)
upstream        git://github.com/hal/core.git (push)

$ git branch -v
* gui_enhancements c1adba1 remove backup pom.xml~ file
  master           5128b4d HAL-335: Workaround using include-aliases=true; more fail-safe RBACGatekeeper

$ git status
# On branch gui_enhancements
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git pull --rebase upstream master
From git://github.com/hal/core
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Current branch gui_enhancements is up to date.
```

The push fail.

```
$ git push origin gui_enhancements
To git@github.com:claudio4j/hal-core
 ! [rejected]        gui_enhancements -> gui_enhancements (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:claudio4j/hal-core'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Looks like my forked repo is not updated compare to upstream
fork: https://github.com/claudio4j/hal-core/commits/gui_enhancements
upstream: https://github.com/hal/core/commits/master

Didn't the "git pull" update my forked repo ?

Is that the cause I cannot push ?

Thanks for your help.

Claudio

Comment: As this is forked repo, only me is working, I did a forced push and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git pull --rebase` does a `fetch` followed by a `rebase`. Rebasing replays commits on top of the new master, so it "changes history"; the old commit at the tip of `gui_enhancements` isn't an ancestor of the new commit.

*If you're the only one using this branch on your fork*, which is probably the case, all you need to do is:

```
git push -f origin gui_enhancements
```

The `-f` will force the push through.

*If other people are collaborating with you on this branch on your fork*, then rewriting history makes things awkward and you should probably use a real (non-`rebase`) pull instead. To redo things this way:

```
# I'm taking the sha that your branch used to be on from the output you pasted.
git reset --hard c1adba1

# No --rebase option.
git pull upstream master

# Since "git pull" did a merge commit this time, it'll be a descendant of the
# old gui_enhancements ref on origin, and the push should succeed.
git push
```

Comment: Hi Ash, when you say "the old commit at the tip of gui_enhancements isn't an ancestor of the new commit." did you see that ? How to check that ? Thanks :)

Comment: The way that rebasing works is by creating new commits that do the same work as the original ones, but on a new parent; so it's intrinsic to the rebasing operation that it changes history destructively like this. You can read about it here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing

Comment: I highly recommend the whole book if you're new to git, by the way. It's a relatively quick read and it'll give you a great idea of what's going on under the scenes with diagrams and such: http://git-scm.com/book/en/